# What is Address family command node in cisco iox

Tags: cisco, routing

What  is  Address family command  node in cisco iox  and  how  can I  use  it?

Comment: What does the manual say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the manual](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_1/switch/command/reference/xrdscmd1.html#wp1025788) (or any one of the manuals, to be more accurate):

> address-family
>
> To enter the address family submode for configuring routing protocols, such as BGP, RIP and static routing, use the address-family command in address family configuration submode. To disable the address family submode for configuring routing protocols, use the no form of this command.

[An explanation of what that actually means (from someone else) below](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2048174).  If you need more explanation than that, I suggest you shouldn't be mucking about on a [production] router, which sounds like it might be good advice in either case.

> The address-family in the BGP configuration allows you to define a
> specific behavior of BGP with regards to many supported Layer3
> protocols:
>
> ```
> IPv4 networks for unicast
> IPv4 networks for multicast
> IPv6 networks for unicast
> IPv6 networks for multicast
> CLNS (NSAP) networks
> ```
>
> The BGP treats all these address families individually, as if it has
> been configured in a separate instance for each of them. These
> individual instances do not leak one into each other (even if they are
> of the same basic type). This way, you can configure a single BGP
> process to maintain several databases of different networks.
>
> The BGP, as a multiprotocol routing protocol, can carry different
> types of routing information in a single BGP session. That means,
> however, that for each of these network types, you need to somehow
> tell the BGP which neighbors also support the same protocol type,
> which routes to inject, how are the individual networks going to be
> filtered or their attributes modified, and so on... That is done in
> the address-family context.
>
> For example, a simple IPv4/IPv6/NSAP BGP could be configured as
> follows:
>
> router bgp 64513
>  bgp log-neighbor-changes
>  neighbor 2001:12::1
> remote-as 64512
>  neighbor 223.255.255.1 remote-as 64512
>  !
> address-family ipv4
>    no neighbor 2001:12::1 activate
>    neighbor
> 223.255.255.1 activate
>    no auto-summary
>    no synchronization exit-address-family
>  !
> address-family ipv6
>    neighbor 2001:12::1
> activate
>  exit-address-family
>  !
>  address-family nsap
>    neighbor
> 223.255.255.1 activate
>    no synchronization
>  exit-address-family
>
> A single BGP process in this case is configured with three address
> families: IPv4, IPv6, and NSAP (the OSI stack). There are two
> neighbors defined, one by its IPv4 address, the second by its IPv6
> address. In my example, both these addresses actually correspond to a
> single neighboring router but of course they do not have to. Now, in
> the address-family ipv4 context, it is configured that the we will
> exchange IPv4 routing information with the neighbor reachable under
> the IP 223.255.255.1. In the address-family ipv6 context, it is
> configured that we will exchange IPv6 routing information with the
> neighbor 2001:12::1. And finally, in the address-family nsap context,
> it is stated that this router will also exchange the routing
> information for CLNS networks with the router 223.255.255.1. All these
> three different Layer3 protocols and their routing information will be
> maintained by this single BGP process but it was necessary to specify
> which neighbors speak which protocols. In addition, if we needed to
> use route-maps, prefix-lists and other attribute manipulations for a
> particular address type, we would also need to define them for
> particular neighbors in their respective address-family contexts.